# table heading overlays text

Tags: tables

I have a small problem with my table formatting. When I run the following code, the headings of the table are hidden underneath the contents of the tables. Also the `cline` does not correctly underline the bottom row of the headings (underneath Risk1, Placebo and Risk). Take below a generic example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Table formatting}
\author{Unknown}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1-1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Introduction}      
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Details}
\lipsum[1-1]
    \end{multicols}

\begin{table}[]
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{The table caption}
        \label{Table:1}
        \begin{tabular}{cccclclc}
            \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{Risk} & \multirow{2}{*}{95\% CI} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Risk\\ Placebo\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{} &
            \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Risk\\ Type A.\end{tabular}} \\
            \cline{3-3} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8}
            \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Non-}\\ \textbf{Female}\end{tabular}} 
            & time1  & 10.4 & [ 8.6--12.5] & & 13.5 & & 18.7 \\
            & time2 & 25.9 & [23.8--28.1] & & 31.1 & & 42.8 \\
            & time3 & 41.2 & [37.5--45.3] & & 47.6 & & 65.3               
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick question: why do you use this mix of `multirow` and nested `tabulars`? I'm quite frankly are having a difficult time understanding how you want the result to look...

Comment: It was used formatted using an online table generator. Can you recommend another method to generate the answer proposed by @David_C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the multirow, which did not appear to be doing anything so I deleted them (also the minipage was unneeded)

```
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{The table caption}
        \label{Table:1}
        \begin{tabular}{cccclclc}
             & 
 &
 Risk & 
95\% CI &
  & 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Risk\\ Placebo\end{tabular} &
  &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Risk\\ Type A.\end{tabular} \\
            \cline{3-3} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8}
            \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Non-}\\ \textbf{Female}\end{tabular}} 
            & time1  & 10.4 & [ 8.6--12.5] & & 13.5 & & 18.7 \\
            & time2 & 25.9 & [23.8--28.1] & & 31.1 & & 42.8 \\
            & time3 & 41.2 & [37.5--45.3] & & 47.6 & & 65.3               
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

The spacing around horizontal rules would be improved if you used the commands from the `booktabs` package.

Answer (score 3):

More or less made with [this Table Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/#). Also added some rules using the `booktabs` package.

By the way, I'd like to recommend the [`siunitx` package](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) for handling numbers (and units) in the table.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
\toprule
        &        & \multirow{2}{*}{Risk} & \multirow{2}{*}{95 \%} & Risk    & Risk  \\
        &        &                       &                        & Placebo & Type A \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Non-Female}        & Time 1 & 10.4 & [ 8.6--12.5] & 13.5    & 18.7   \\
                  & Time 2 & 25.9 & [23.8--28.1] & 31.1    & 42.8   \\
                  & Time 3 & 41.2 & [37.5--45.3] & 47.6    & 65.3   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but did you use `siunitx` in this example?

Comment: As there is no `\usepackage{siunitx}` in my MWE: no. But I'd introduce it if I were you. For example you'd be able to write `\SI{95}{\percent}`, and should be able to get your numbers aligned around the decimal separator.